# Note taking software that allows references to database

Tags: database, note-taking

I was wondering if the following already existed:

I want a software to take notes. But sometimes when you take notes (for example in sciences class) you have the same definition that you have to write multiple time depending the lesson.

It would be amazing if there were any way to do the following (or something similar):

I write for the first time the definition of cat: "def(cat):"blabla" " so it register it into a table of definition that is in an external database (in SQL for example).
Then, if in another lesson I have to write this definition again, I would simply note "def(cat)" and when I render my file the full definition will be written on the file.

Have you heard of anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using wiki software for your notes.  This will allow you to create a page for each definition, or a page for related definitions or a whole topic, and then hyperlink to that page from the notes page where you want to reference it.

An example of such software is [Zim Wiki](https://zim-wiki.org/).

Comment: That's almost what I wanted. But when I export it to pdf, I want the definition to be shown too (I want to print the notes). I that possible with such software ?

Comment: If you print the pages containing definitions along with the note pages.  Neither Zim nor any other wiki software I know of will pull the contents of a linked page into the linking page when printing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen an example exactly like you're requesting, but I'm sure it could be done either natively on [coda.io](https://coda.io) or connecting other apps with Coda via [Zapier Coda Integrations](https://zapier.com/app-directory/coda/integrations).

They are both free and powerful tools capable of extreme customization.

I currently use [Notion.so](https://Notion.so) for most of my note-taking and organization, but it has limits to its capabilities.